# Why are results different when a logarithmic function is applied on same regular matrix and Sparse Matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

When I am trying to apply `log` function on same regular and sparse matrix, the results obtained are different. Is there anything that I should keep in mind while applying these kind of functions? Below is a reproducible example.

```
TestMatrix = matrix(c(3,1,0,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,6,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),5,byrow = TRUE)
TestSparseMatrix = Matrix(TestMatrix,sparse = TRUE)
# Logarithmic function when applied to regular matrix
 -log(TestMatrix / rowSums(TestMatrix), 2)


#Output
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
#[1,] 0.4150375 2.000000      Inf      Inf  Inf
#[2,] 0.3219281      Inf 2.321928      Inf  Inf
#[3,] 1.5849625 2.584963 2.584963 1.584963  Inf
#[4,] 0.4150375 3.000000      Inf 3.000000  Inf
#[5,] 0.0000000      Inf      Inf      Inf  Inf


# Logarithmic function when applied to Sparse matrix
-log(TestSparseMatrix / rowSums(TestSparseMatrix), 2)


# Output
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
#[1,] 0.2876821 1.386294      Inf      Inf  Inf
#[2,] 0.2231436      Inf 1.609438      Inf  Inf
#[3,] 1.0986123 1.791759 1.791759 1.098612  Inf
#[4,] 0.2876821 2.079442      Inf 2.079442  Inf
#[5,] 0.0000000      Inf      Inf      Inf  Inf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log()` is ignoring `base` for a sparse matrix (an "S4" object). Using `log2` eliminates the problem:

```
-log2(TestSparseMatrix / rowSums(TestSparseMatrix))
```

Have a read on "S4 methods" part of `?log`. I believe this is not commonly known.

```
Note that this means that the S4 generic for ‘log’ has a signature
with only one argument, ‘x’, but that ‘base’ can be passed to
methods (but will not be used for method selection).  On the other
hand, if you only set a method for the ‘Math’ group generic then
‘base’ argument of ‘log’ will be ignored for your class.
```

In case you wonder, you can read further on:

```
?groupGeneric
?S4groupGeneric
```

or equivalently (as you will be redirected to the above manual pages):

```
?base::Math
?methods::Math
```

This is really related to how "Math" group is defined. Specially quoted from `?S4groupGeneric`:

```
Note that two members of the ‘Math’ group, ‘log’ and ‘trunc’, have
... as an extra formal argument.  Since methods for ‘Math’ will
have only one formal argument, you must set a specific method for
these functions in order to call them with the extra argument(s).
```

---

So what if you want take logarithm with an arbitrary, valid `base`, say `base = 3`? Use formula:

```
log(x, base = 3) = log(x) / log(3)
```

For example, with your `TestSparseMatrix`, you can also do:

```
-log(TestSparseMatrix / rowSums(TestSparseMatrix)) / log(2)
```